# getting inconsistent behaviour when passing timestamp between spark and pandas

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, parquet, apache-arrow

I'm trying to share a dataframe between spark and pandas, and encounter strange behaviour in handling time stamps (for time stamps generated in non configuration UTC)

given a data frame with both a time stamp top level field, and a timestamp in the nested field, they will treated differently

```
df1.show(vertical=True, truncate=False)
-RECORD 0---------------------------
 id  | 1                            
 ts1 | 2021-05-02 04:21:15.918449   
 ts2 | {2021-05-02 04:21:15.918449} 
-RECORD 1---------------------------
 id  | 2                            
 ts1 | 2021-05-02 04:21:15.918449   
 ts2 | {2021-05-02 04:21:15.918449} 
-RECORD 2---------------------------
 id  | 3                            
 ts1 | 2021-05-02 04:21:15.918449   
 ts2 | {2021-05-02 04:21:15.918449} 

df1.toPandas()
    id  ts1 ts2
0   1   2021-05-02 04:23:36.438987  (2021-05-02 11:23:36.438987,)
1   2   2021-05-02 04:23:36.438987  (2021-05-02 11:23:36.438987,)
2   3   2021-05-02 04:23:36.438987  (2021-05-02 11:23:36.438987,)
```

in a top level field the timestamp is displayed as a local time, and in the nested as UTC.

when trying to save the dataframe to parquet and read it from pandas results are changed even more, and the nested values is converted to int (nanoseconds from epoch), and the top level value remains as it was.

notebook with runnable example:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QWivTFHR7SS91pVBvCAbpJ3lYWgw0Nk1?usp=sharing

any idea what is the source of the inconsistency?

**EDIT**

some more data

the schema of the dataframe:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ts1: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- ts2: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- col1: timestamp (nullable = false)
```

df1.head()

```
Row(id=1, ts1=datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 2, 12, 3, 25, 809113), ts2=Row(col1=datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 2, 12, 3, 25, 809113)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the source of inconsistency is the representation of the struct, which is a Spark Row object containing a Python datetime object. So in the pandas dataframe, `ts1` column has a pandas datetime type, while `ts2` column has a Spark Row type (you can confirm this by selecting `df1.toPandas().t2[0]`).

The problem with Spark Row types is that it uses the Python datetime object, which follows the Python timezone rather than the Spark Session timezone. Spark is perhaps too smart to realize that, and so during the conversion from a dataframe to the Row object, it will take into account the difference between the Spark Session timezone and the Python timezone, thus giving the difference you observed.

To get around this issue, you can set the Python timezone as below, before you call `.toPandas()`:

```
import os
import time

os.environ['TZ'] = 'America/Los_Angeles'
time.tzset()
```

Comment: setting the python time zone does help, but the types are the same - added details to the question

Comment: a timestamp is different from a Row(timestamp). Row/struct can contain many different fields, and is handled in a different way